# Save java SWT chart to image

Tags: java, eclipse, save, swt, swtchart

I have a java application using org.eclipse.swtchart (https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/science.swtchart/downloads). I would like to save the outputted chart to a .jpg or similar image format instead of having the chart displayed, thus far I am at a loss as to how to do so. The code is not fully complete yet, I intend to have it monitor a specific file for CSV files and automatically create and save a graphic from the available data.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;[enter image description here][1]
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import org.eclipse.swtchart.Chart;
import org.eclipse.swtchart.IAxis;
import org.eclipse.swtchart.IAxisSet;
import org.eclipse.swtchart.IBarSeries;
import org.eclipse.swtchart.IGrid;
import org.eclipse.swtchart.ISeries.SeriesType;
import org.eclipse.swtchart.LineStyle;
import org.eclipse.swtchart.Range;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class CSVBarChart[enter image description here][1] {

    private static double[] ySeries;
    private static String [] xSeries; 

    /**
     * The main method.
     * 
     * @param args
     *            the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\FAD-Export\\42510149_10101764726495991_5660171154099273728_o.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                br.readLine();
            line = br.readLine(); 

                // use comma as separator
                String[] stringSeries = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                String[] xSeries1 = {"Face    " + stringSeries[0],
                        "Condifence    " + stringSeries[1],
                        "AU01 Inner Brow Raiser    " + stringSeries[2],
                        "AU02 Outer Brow Raiser    " + stringSeries[3],
                        "AU04 Brow Lowerer    " + stringSeries[4],
                        "AU05 Upper Lid Raiser    " + stringSeries[5],
                        "AU06 Cheek Raiser    " + stringSeries[6],
                        "AU07 Lid Tightener    " + stringSeries[7],
                        "AU09 Nose Wrinkler    " + stringSeries[8],
                        "AU10 Upper Lip Raiser    " + stringSeries[9],
                        "AU12 Lip Corner Puller    " + stringSeries[10],
                        "AU14 Dimpler    " + stringSeries[11],
                        "AU15 Lip Corner Depressor    " + stringSeries[12],
                        "AU17 Chin Raiser    " + stringSeries[13],
                        "AU20 Lip Stretcher    " + stringSeries[14],
                        "AU23 Lip Tightener    " + stringSeries[15],
                        "AU25 Lips Part    " + stringSeries[16],
                        "AU26 Jaw Drop    " + stringSeries[17],
                        "AU45 Blink    " + stringSeries[18]};
                xSeries = xSeries1;
                ySeries = Arrays.stream(stringSeries)
                        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                        .toArray();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("");
        shell.setSize(900, 900);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        createChart(shell);
        shell.open();
        while(!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if(!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }


    /**
     * create the chart.
     * 
     * @param parent
     *            The parent composite
     * @return The created chart
     */
    static public Chart createChart(Composite parent) {

        // create a chart
        Chart chart = new Chart(parent, SWT.NONE);
        chart.setOrientation(SWT.VERTICAL);
        // set titles
        chart.getTitle().setText("Bar Chart");
        IAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0);
        yAxis.setRange(new Range(0, 5));

        IAxis xAxis = chart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0);

        xAxis.setCategorySeries(xSeries);
        xAxis.enableCategory(true);
        xAxis.setRange(new Range(2, 20));

        IAxisSet axisSet = chart.getAxisSet();
        IGrid xGrid = axisSet.getXAxis(0).getGrid();
        xGrid.setStyle(LineStyle.NONE);


        chart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).getTitle().setText("Action Units");
        chart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0).getTitle().setText("Intensity");
        // create bar series
        IBarSeries barSeries = (IBarSeries)chart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.BAR, "AU Intensity");
        barSeries.setYSeries(ySeries);

        return chart;
    }
```

}

Comment: `Chart` has a `save` method to save to a file

Comment: @greg-449 - THANK YOU! I don't know how that escaped my search. To resolve I set chart to be a field, and added line chart.save("barchart.jpeg", SWT.IMAGE_JPEG); in thread main under shell.open();. I also set shell.setVisible(false); right under chart.save. I am unable as of yet to completely hide the shell but this at least lasts for 1/2 a second.